# DNN 7 issue with SupportedModules attribute

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I'm an experienced (ASP.NET|Java|PHP|web) developer, new to DotNetNuke.

Currently I'm following a blog tutorial to try to get an Angular module up-and-running in my local installation of DNN 7 (http://www.bitboxx.net/Blog/Post/505/DNN-module-development-with-AngularJS-Part-1#)

My environment: Windows 2012 Server R2, SQL Server 2016 Express, Visual Studio 2015 and DNN 7 on IIS 8.

DNN nuke runs fine.

I installed the downloaded module from the blog to my DNN. I'm having problems to run the HelloWorld example (at the bottom of the 2nd part of the course).
Through some trial-and-error I found out this has to do with the [SupportedModules] attribute on the controller.
Without this attribute it runs fine, but with the attribute it won't.

How does DNN determine the name of the module? The "installation" process was no more then unzipping the modules contents to the DesktopModules directory within my DNN directory (in inetput\wwwroot).

Do I need to install/configure the modules in Settings > Extensions?

Or am I missing some other point with regards to the DNN 7's security?

Thanks in advance for any help/thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install the module through the Extensions mechanism in DNN. This will register the module so DNN is aware of the module as well as make sure the files get copied to the right places, in accordance with the installation manifest (the .dnn file you should find inside that .zip file)

However, looking at the blog article you referenced, I don't see an actual installation zip file anywhere. The only download I found was for the project as a whole. You would need to package your compiled solution into an installable zip file (with a .dnn manifest file) or you need to manually register your extension from the Extensions page.

[image: Where to find the Extensions page in DNN 7]

On that page you should click the "Create New Extension" button which will walk you through supplying details for the module. Choose Module as the Extension Type

[image: Create New Extension Button]

Only a few of the items are required. The "Name" you use for the module will be the name you use in SupportedModules. It will also default your folder name (the folder in /DesktopModules) to the module name. Friendly Name, incidentally, is what will be displayed in menus and such.

Once you've created the module it should be registered with DNN. You will probably need to restart your AppPool and website for the change to take effect.

FYI, SupportedModules isn't strictly required. If you're building this for a client and not building this for distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, but thanks for your information! This does help my understanding of DNN.